# Cannot edit the file

Tags: php, editor

```
 <?php 
    $filename = "Changelog.txt"; 
    $newdata = $_POST['newd']; 
    if ($newdata != '')
    { 
        $fw = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Could not open file! Error 1'); 
        $fb = fwrite($fw,stripslashes($newdata)) or die('Could not write to file'); 
        fclose($fw); 
    } 
    $fh = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Could not open file!"); 
    $data = fread($fh, filesize($filename)) or die("Could not read file! Error 2"); 
    fclose($fh); 
        echo
            "<form action='$_SERVER[php_self]' method= 'post' > 
            <textarea name='newd' cols='100%' rows='50'> $data </textarea> 
            <input type='submit' value='Change'> 
            </form>"; 
?>
```

So I found a code from google to add a file editor, it successfully shows the file to the editor, but when I add new line and click change, it says `"Could not open file"`. Could you help me out?

Comment: Just change one Could not open file! message and see from which section you are getting ther error.

Comment: I'm getting the error 1.

Comment: Check with thsese fopen($filename, 'w+') / fopen($filename, 'a') /  fopen($filename, 'a+')  and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This editor can open file for reading and fails when you try to open it for writing.

It's probably not a php issue. It's the filesystem that prevents writing access. There are several solutions: Give the directory 777 rights, let your webuser own the directory or let it join a group that has permissions, ...

Navigate to the log directory and try sudo chmod -R 777 .

I presume you have linux.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely file path is wrong, please check the path and give the absolute path.

example:

```
$filename = "D:\project\Changelog.txt";
```